# The Rest API not working in postman when requested by url

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, postman, lumen-5.4

I have start server by this cmd in the console, and it is working fine

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

When i call the API in postman for the lumen like this:

```
localhost:8000/GitHub/twinfield/public/index.php/user
```

The API work for insert but when i call like this:

```
localhost:8000/GitHub/twinfield/user
```

The error is given below:

> (1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php (line 226) at
>   Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(0)) in RoutesRequests.php
>   (line 164) at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}() in
>   RoutesRequests.php (line 413) at
>   Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in
>   RoutesRequests.php (line 166) at Application->dispatch(null) in
>   RoutesRequests.php (line 107) at Application->run() in index.php (line
>   28)

My routes file in routes/web.php:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    //print_r('1234');die;
    return $router->app->version();
});

$router->get('user','userController@index');
$router->get('user/{id}','userController@getuser');      
$router->post('user','userController@createuser');
$router->post('user/{id}','userController@updateuser');    
$router->delete('user/{id}','userController@deleteuser');
```

I have already try to solve like this in public/index.php without success.

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);
```

I am working in localhost with Xampp. The database is MySQL and PHP version is 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, you forget the url link or may be missed. Its always when we start the server(In the laravel the command is php artisan serve), It always belongs to that path from where it is called.

Like in your case, your path is xampp/htdocs/GItHub/twinfield where the lumen reside(i suppose).

```
localhost:8000/GitHub/twinfield/public/index.php/user
```

so if you called like this:

```
localhost:8000/GitHub/twinfield/user
```

It is never worked because you defined the route:

```
$router->get('user','userController@index'); 
$router->post('user','userController@createuser');
```

thats why  you have to use only the name of the route and type. Open postman and add this line with type->get:

```
localhost:8000/user
```

you will get all users in the DB. If you add this line with the type->post.

```
localhost:8000/user
```

Than you should post the body with the field of the Table in which you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to many solution I feel that a stupid mistake I have made. That is the url:

```
localhost:8000/GitHub/twinfield/user
```

Because the new server is starting by the command so it is belongs to that url. So I have use this url in the postman with get and than post.

```
localhost:8000/user
```

and you know it just run like a charm. No need for anything else in this solution.